# unique equilibrium in a perturbed system

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, dynamical-systems, perturbation-theory

In today's lecture, I see that if $x_*$ is an asymptotic stable and hyperbolic equilibrium of the $\dot{x}=a(x), \, x\in\mathbb{R}^n$. But then prof said that "it's obvious" if we give a small $\epsilon$ s.t. $\dot{x}=a(x)+\epsilon b(x)$, then we can obtain another equilibrium $x_{**}$ near $x_*$ and it is unique. We assume $a,b$ are all smooth.

I feel this is obvious since we move the system a little bit by $\epsilon$, but I wonder how to write out a proof rigorously.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: Implicit function theorem.

Let $f(x,\epsilon)=a(x)+\epsilon b(x)$. Then $Df_x(x_*,0)=Da(x_*).$ Why do the assumptions allow us to conclude $f(x(\epsilon),\epsilon)=0$ for small $\epsilon$?

Comment: By “aasumption", do you mean $a,b$ are smooth vector field?

Comment: And what does $x(\epsilon)$ mean here inside $f(x(\epsilon),\epsilon)$?

Comment: Do you mean this new equilibrium $x_{**}$ is dependent on $\epsilon$?

Comment: I have double checked I.F.T and in our case, we have that: (1)$f(x_*,0)=c=0$, (2)Since $Df_{x}(x_*,0)\ne 0$, then there exists a n.b.h of $(x_*,0)$ so that $\epsilon$ is sufficiently small implies $f(x(\epsilon),\epsilon)=c=0$. Is it right?

Comment: That's the idea. But since $x:\mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}^n$, you really have to show that $Df_x(x_*,0)$ is invertible, or has nonzero determinant. Why does the fact that the fixed point is stable and hyperbolic ensure this fact?

Comment: Why do I need to show $Df_{*}(x_x,0)$ is invertible? What would happen if it isn't?

Comment: Hyperbolic means that all eigenvalues have nonzero real parts, and asymptoticity implies the nonzero real parts are actually all negative. The point is to make sure no eigenvalue is 0, which implies the Jacobian nonsigular.

Answer (score 0):

Continuing on @zugzug answer, you need to argue that whether the $Da(x_*)$ is invertible or not(yes it is true), then using the [Implicit Function Theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Implicit_function_theorem), you can finish up your proof.